# Extracting certificate parts to sign file with OpenSSL

Tags: ssl, openssl, code-signing, code-signing-certificate, signtool

I wish to sign a .mobileconfig file using the following command:

```
openssl smime \
-sign \
-signer your-cert.pem \
-inkey your-priv-key.pem \
-certfile TheCertChain.pem \
-nodetach \
-outform der \
-in ConfigProfile.mobileconfig \
-out ConfigProfile_signed.mobileconfig
```

I have an SSL certificate which was requested and installed on my machine, and a code-signing certificate which was requested and installed on my machine.

Now which certificate should I be using (code signing or SSL?), and how do I get hold of the `your-cert.pem`,`your-priv-key.pem` and `TheCertChain.pem` files?

Visiting GoDaddy again just gives me a single .pem file, and I do not know which one that even is.

Running `openssl x509 -in godaddy.pem -inform pem -noout -text` on the .pem from GoDaddy gives the following:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 0 (0x0)
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, O=The Go Daddy Group, Inc., OU=Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
        Validity
            Not Before: Jun 29 17:06:20 2004 GMT
            Not After : Jun 29 17:06:20 2034 GMT
        Subject: C=US, O=The Go Daddy Group, Inc., OU=Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:de:9d:d7:ea:57:18:49:a1:5b:eb:d7:5f:48:86:
                    ea:be:dd:ff:e4:ef:67:1c:f4:65:68:b3:57:71:a0:
                    ****REMOVED FOR BREVITY****
                    58:c6:44:7b:0a:3e:62:28:5f:ba:41:07:53:58:cf:
                    11:7e:38:74:c5:f8:ff:b5:69:90:8f:84:74:ea:97:
                    1b:af
                Exponent: 3 (0x3)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                D2:C4:****REMOVED FOR BREVITY****:A8:6A:D4:E3
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:D2:C4:****REMOVED FOR BREVITY****D:A8:6A:D4:E3
                DirName:/C=US/O=The Go Daddy Group, Inc./OU=Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
                serial:00

            X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
                CA:TRUE
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
         32:4b:f3:b2:ca:3e:91:fc:12:c6:a1:07:8c:8e:77:a0:33:06:
         14:5c:90:1e:18:f7:08:a6:3d:0a:19:f9:87:80:11:6e:69:e4:
         96:17:30:ff:34:91:63:72:38:ee:cc:1c:01:a3:1d:94:28:a4:
         ****REMOVED FOR BREVITY****
         10:43:a6:a5:9e:0a:d5:95:62:9a:0d:cf:88:82:c5:32:0c:e4:
         2b:9f:45:e6:0d:9f:28:9c:b1:b9:2a:5a:57:ad:37:0f:af:1d:
         7f:db:bd:9f
```

Comment: What's your programming question?

Comment: Run the command `openssl x509 -in godaddy.pem -inform pem -noout -text`  - this will tell you what GoDaddy included in the .pem they gave you.  Either post the results with the private fingerprint obfuscated, or update your answer with more details.

Comment: I've posted this. What command do I run to extract `your-cert.pem` and `your-priv-key.pem`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to sign with your private key, cert, and chain.

`your-cert.pem` is the certificate that GoDaddy issued you.

`your-priv-key.pem` is the private key you generated on your keychain or on the command line to create the CSR.

`TheCertChain.pem` is GoDaddy's certificate chain, you can find that on their website

FYI here's example code on how I'm signing a .mobileconfig in Ruby https://github.com/AppBlade/TestHub/blob/master/app/controllers/devices_controller.rb#L31